# Center a movie clip on a child mc's position for map locations

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a map movie clip named "map" with a bunch of building clips in it. Each building is a movie clip that you can click. I need to center the map on that clicked item. How can i make this work?

```
//This doesn't make the map move where i need it to
function moveMap(childmc:String):void {
    Tweener.addTween(themap, {x:themap[childmc].x, time:1, transition:"easeOutCubic"});
    Tweener.addTween(themap, {y:themap[childmc].y, time:1, transition:"easeOutCubic"});
}
```

Any help would be great, been searching for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function objClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var target_x = STAGE_WIDTH/2 - e.target.x;
    var target_y = STAGE_HEIGHT/2 - e.target.y;

    TweenLite.to(map_mc, 1, {x: target_x, y: target_y})
}
```

Sorry making a lot different code than your sample, but I think this way is better.

**[EDIT]**
I tested this code, and it worked. The clickable movieclip are inside another movieclip called "map_mc".
STAGE_WIDTH/HEIGHT were my stage size, but you can addapt to your viewport.

Comment: I tried that just now -  but when i click on the child clips, the parent clip (map) goes off the screen. I've got the registration points in the center for both children and parent (map) btw. Basically i need to be able to click the child clips, and have the parent clip tween so that the clicked clip is in the center of the viewport.

Comment: Edited - See now if you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks again, have a great weekend, so relieved!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to tween a parent MC to the location of a MC that is nested inside it.  If that is not what you are trying to do, perhaps {this[childmc].x, this[childmc].y} in the object that describes where you are tweening to might help?  Also, should the time and transition be inside that object or outside? I'm a Tweensy user, so I'm not sure, but it doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: The tweener code is definitely right, what isn't right is that the map doesn't center on the child clip at all. It moves the map, but it's not centering on the child clip.

Comment: OK, your code is definitely right. Remind me why you're having an issue again?